# discerning between "racism" and" supremacist "

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

Do anyone know what is the difference between the two?

racism

supremacist

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Racism is a belief and a supremacist is a person who advocates a certain belief.  @Stephie I think you misread racism as racist. Nima, why wasn't a dictionary helpful here?

Comment: @ColleenV: Being German, maybe I'm biased and over-sensitive... Yet let me quote the first sentence about racism at wikipedia: "Racism consists of ideologies and practices that seek to justify, or cause, the unequal distribution of privileges, rights or goods among different racial groups."

Comment: @Stephie Sorry, I could have been more clear. I wasn't disagreeing with you, just critiquing your grammar :) Racism should be replaced with idiocy maybe, while supremacist is fine as idiot.

Comment: @ColleenV Well, I was just ignoring the fact that one was a principle, the other a person - keeping the author in mind...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All racial supremacists are racists, but not all racists are supremacists.

The supremacist believes that races can be ranked on a scale of quality (putting his or her own usually at the top).

The racist believes that race can account for behavior.

I should add that "race" is understood by the racist and the supremacist to be a set of biological traits. They're not referring to *ethnicity*.